# Is it possible to release only instant app without installable version?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have only one module and I want my whole app to be an instant app without any other installable modules. Is it possible to release this app in play store only as an instant app or do I also have to release it under the Standard release type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to release it as a regular app as well under the Standard release type.